# Unable to select value for multi-select field

Tags: karate

I have read the documentation and examples on this and they are not working in my instance. The html looks like:

```html
<div class="col-md-10 text-left">
                <select class="list" id="numbers" multiple="multiple" name="numbers"><option value="1">111.222.333</option>
<option value="2">555.666.7777</option>
<option value="3">123.456.7899</option>
<option value="4">153.246.0987</option>
<option value="5">234.543.1231</option>
</select>
</div>

* def randomValue = '555.666.7777'
* select('#numbers', randomValue)
```

I have tried the above, however, the value of randomValue variable does not get selected. I have also tried to use querySelector, however, I don't think it's capable of sending text.

The ONLY time this has worked is when I have used the following:

```
* select('#numbers', '{}555.666.7777')
```

However, the above doesn't work for me because I cannot hardcode that value. I need to be variablized since I am using dynamic values on each run.

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamic values can be used almost everwhere in Karate. For example:

```
* def data = '555.666.7777'
* select('#numbers', '{}' + data)
```

Comment: I had ended up doing this as well. Thank you!